# Spring Batch - Failed to initialize the reader

Tags: java, xml, spring, batch-processing

> **Solution:** The file path of the .csv file that needs to be transformed
>   is wrong

---

i'm having some issues trying to run a batch spring application.

Objectives: I want to read a csv file and load it on a class (my boss told me that), what i know for sure is that the sample of code that i use, directly charges the data to MySQL.

Here i post a picture of my project:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieEmK.png

-Here are the files-

App.java

```
package springbach;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] springConfig  = 
        {   "database.xml", 
            "context.xml",
            "job-report.xml" 
        };

    ApplicationContext context = 
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
    Job job = (Job) context.getBean("reportJob");

    try {

        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
        System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Done");

  }
}
```

Report.java

```
package springbach;


public class Report {

    private String Date;
    private String Impressions;
    private String Clicks;
    private String Earning;


    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        Date = date;
    }
    public String getImpressions() {
        return Impressions;
    }
    public void setImpressions(String impressions) {
        Impressions = impressions;
    }
    public String getClicks() {
        return Clicks;
    }
    public void setClicks(String clicks) {
        Clicks = clicks;
    }
    public String getEarning() {
        return Earning;
    }
    public void setEarning(String earning) {
        Earning = earning;
    }

}
```

context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

  <!-- stored job-metadata in database -->
  <bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseType" value="mysql" />
  </bean>

  <!-- stored job-metadata in memory -->
  <!-- 
  <bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
  </bean>
   -->

  <bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
  </bean>

</beans>
```

database.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd">

  <!-- connect to database -->
  <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

  <!-- create job-meta tables automatically -->
  <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql" />
  </jdbc:initialize-database>

</beans>
```

job-report.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

  <bean id="report" class="springbach.Report" scope="prototype" />

  <batch:job id="reportJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
      <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="cvsFileItemReader" writer="mysqlItemWriter"
            commit-interval="2">
        </batch:chunk>
      </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
  </batch:job>

  <bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">

    <!-- Read a csv file -->
    <property name="resource" value="file:C:\Java\workspace\springbach\src\main\java\springbachdata.csv" />

    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
          <!-- split it -->
          <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
              class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                <property name="names" value="date,impressions,clicks,earning" />
            </bean>
          </property>
          <property name="fieldSetMapper">   
                 <!-- return back to reader, rather than a mapped object. -->
                 <!--
             <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PassThroughFieldSetMapper" />
                  --> 
              <!-- map to an object -->
              <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="report" />
              </bean>           
          </property>

          </bean>
      </property>

  </bean>

  <bean id="mysqlItemWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql">
      <value>
            <![CDATA[        
                insert into RAW_REPORT(DATE,IMPRESSIONS,CLICKS,EARNING) 
            values (:date, :impressions, :clicks, :earning)
            ]]>
      </value>
    </property>
    <!-- It will take care matching between object property and sql name parameter -->
    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
        <bean
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

-Here is my console error-

```
Nov 13, 2013 9:24:52 AM org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep execute
SEVERE: Encountered an error executing the step
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:192)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:137)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:152)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:131)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127)
    at springbach.App.main(App.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): URL [file:C:/Java/workspace/springbach/src/main/java/springbachdata.csv]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:139)
    ... 14 more

Nov 13, 2013 9:24:53 AM org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1 run
INFO: Job: [FlowJob: [name=reportJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [FAILED]
Exit Status : FAILED
Done
```

Comment: Make sure that the file which you are trying to read exist in given path..file:C:/Java/workspace/springbach/src/main/java/springbachdata.csv

Comment: Also if your file is in your classpath then use classpath:/springbatchdata.csv

Comment: Thanks it was the file, now is working n.n

Comment: how you have fixed it?

Comment: That issue yes, now is giving me an MySQL DB exception xd

Comment: Now is full working, thanks a lot man n.n

Comment: Can you post the answer what fixed your problem ?

Answer (score 6):

The exception states that it is not able to resolve class path resource. So you can try using file:springbachdata.csv or classpath:springbachdata.csv, if springbachdata.csv is under resource folder.